# How can I configure git to give an output message for the add command?

Tags: git, version-control, windows-7-x64

I used to exclusively use Subversion via the Subclipse plugin for Eclipse and TortoiseSVN. My company migrated to git and at first I was using SourceTree, but have moved over to the command line as of late and I'm noticing some commands have very poor output.

For example, if I do `git add --all`, it will stage any changes I have, but doesn't tell me that it did anything: there is only one blank line of output. How can I configure git to tell me what files were staged via `git add --all`?

I'm sure there are other commands with unhelpful output, but this is the one I can think of at the moment.

Comment: doesn't the `--verbose ` flag give you some info? you might create an [alias](https://githowto.com/aliases) so that it is always used.

Comment: I believe this does what I'm looking for. Maybe the git add documentation could use some updating. 
`-v
--verbose
Be verbose.` This documentation tells me "Make current output more verbose" not "Actually have output". I guess t's difficult to search for this when the only keyword that can find it is "verbose"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Timothy Truckle gave a sufficient answer. `git add --all --verbose` does have output when any files are staged.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use `git add --all --verbose` which will output what was staged.

There is no way to make this the default behaviour. While there is a `commit.verbose` config option, there is not an `add.verbose` config option.

Alternative approaches to your problem:

After using `git add` you can use `git status` to see staged changes

You could try adding changes explicitly rather than using `--all`.
Note that `--all` adds all changes from the whole working tree, not just the current directory.

See the [pathspec docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec) for how you can use directory names, wildcards, keywords and more to specify which files should be added. For example
`git add a/**/b` matches `a/b`, `a/x/b`, `a/x/y/b` and so on.